# Variations in math to implement three-dimensional space?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Backstory**:
So I was researching topics, and found that 3-D game programming often markets itself with linear algebra. As a philosopher of math I decided to dig further into this and determine if linear algebra is in fact the only option. It turns out that there's "sub-parts" of linear algebra, such as vector mathematics with eigenvectors and eigenvalues, transformation matrices, and the whole system readily implements matrix math. At first I thought, "Well, there can't only be one way to do anything."

**Questioning:**
So I thought I'd come here to reason, ask questions, and attempt to challenge and/or validate the reasoning behind them. My questions are simple, and here they are:

1.**Is vector math (Euclidean geometry, transformation matrices) the *only way possible* in math to implement a three-dimensional geometric world?** : Citation needed.

2.**Why has vector math been a de-facto standard for three-dimensional computer programming, and graphics programming over the years?** : Expecting answer.

3.**What can stop, or why could one not implement a form of vector math, instead, only under one's personal protocol, system, or foundation?**

I have researched, and it's very possible that, with existing systems, one could easily create a new system to represent three-dimensional space without vector math, or vectors in general. **Why aren't other methods talked about, and why is vector math treated as the only possible way to visualize, implement, or control motion in three-dimensional space?**

Other possible systems:

1.[Hyperbolic geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry).

2.Cartesian-coordinate system with extended Z-axis, or a third axis for the third dimension.

3.[Spherical-only-coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system).

What is the hype with vectors? I mean, it's possible to represent three-dimensional worlds without vector math in particular, so why is it so preferred?

To ease this up, I'll ask again to make this question "acceptable." What other systems exist to represent 3-D spacial-coordinate systems outside of vector maths?

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė I didn't say what can replace linear math, I said vector math in particular. And whether or not linear math is easy depends on the person.

Comment: *"Linear algebra is the branch of mathematics concerning vector spaces"*. I don't know what you're saying.

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://gamelab.mit.edu/games/a-slower-speed-of-light/

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė I know that the branch concerns vector spaces, but I want to know if there's any other [mathematical structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_structure) besides vector space to illustrate or implement within a system.

Comment: @BabyDragon What about it? That doesn't concern my questioning here at all; that's a game development toolkit. I'm asking about the theory, preference, structure, and implementation of three-dimensional coordinates and space, and how these things can be represented without vectors.

Comment: @AWH There are lots of structures that one could use in principle; vector spaces are common because they are several orders of magnitude easier than almost anything else one could come up with.  One might try using, for example, the theory of finite groups, to encode possible rotations of the player's view.  But the most powerful tool in studying finite groups of any appreciable size and complexity is representation theory—i.e., realizing the group in relation to some vector space.

Comment: @User-33433 From my experience, if you ask me, vector space over complicates some aspects of transformation matrices over a player's view. For example, one needs not rotate three matrices in every transformation just to adjust something in relation to something else.

Comment: @AWH To work with something simpler than vector spaces, it would be necessary to neuter the geometry in some way.  For example, if we give up distance, we might use graph theory—board games are a good example of this.  But as soon as you want to deal with actual geometrical relationships, that kind of model falls apart.

Comment: @AWH You can't really say that a given model over-complicates things when you're not comparing it to any alternative.  There may be easier or harder ways of performing specific calculations, but you're talking about substituting entirely different conceptual models.  And there are lots of possible models, but they are all either a) not geometric, or b) non-linear, hence intrinsically subject to all the over-complication you're fretting about for vector spaces, times a billion.

Comment: @AWH I think that future work in topos theory might provide a tighter link between linguistic expression and mathematical models, and might smooth out some of the bumps you're concerned about.  But asking for a simpler geometry than linear algebra is like asking for a simpler counting system than the natural numbers.  There just aren't a lot of moving parts.

Comment: @AWH Let me add that there's another interpretation of your question, namely: Why vectors, rather than some different encoding of the same mathematics, such as turtle graphics, or Euclidean-style reasoning?  There, the answer is more subtle, and largely has to do with the way that computer memory is accessed, making uniform block-type operations preferable any time computational speed is a concern.  If speed isn't a concern, then you're right: there's no particularly good reason to deal only with vectors as such.  Domain-specific languages are usually best, if one can afford the luxury.

Answer (score 2):

1. No. Vector math's not the only way. But since it was invented to represent physical systems, it's no surprise that it's so very successful. You could do everything with point-sets, and indeed, the point-based graphics folks partly do that. They still use vector mathematics to compute the projected image of the 3D world onto the image plane, but that's because it's easy.
2. See 1.
3. I don't believe I understand the question.

You might want to look at Karan Singh's paper (P. Coleman, K. Singh. RYAN: Render  Your Animation Non-Linearly projected (ACM Nonphotorealistic Rendering and Animation NPAR 2004) pp 129-138. (NSERC, MITACS)) on using non-linear projections in computer graphics.

Comment: Thumbs up, but if you don't understand question three, I'll make it crystal-clear for you: Why aren't there many other systems? Why does it all boil down to a single, uniform way? I mean there's dozens of ways to project 2-D graphics ... why are there so few for 3-D? And saying "because it's easy." doesn't exactly answer the question, but thumbs up nonetheless for your effort. Also, you might have wanted to cite some of your wording there: [Set Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory)

Comment: When I wrote my first 3D graphics program (ca '76), I don't believe I used any linear algebra -- just some similar triangles. But when I saw that you could use matrices and do lots of stuff in a more compact, more easily debuggable way, I started using that.

In much the same way, when I was a kid I figured out how to count in binary, and to find the binary representation of 72, I'd count to 72 in binary. Then I realized I could just work out how many 64s, how many 32s, etc.  That was faster and more reliable.

But as I say, other methods of doing graphics, including basic geometry, work fine.

Comment: Yes, and I'm not necessarily against it. It's just my personal job to question and reason why one system is treated as perfect when others may or could exist. It's a bit like the battle between [string theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory) and [nanotechnology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanotechnology).

Comment: There is really no such thing as not using linear algebra. Whether you write it in matrices is a matter of notation.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė You might want to consider where you stand philosophically on this subject. I wasn't asking for a replacement of linear algebra, but for the notion of vector math, and how to work out [mathematical structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_structure) therein that differ in approach.